# C# SQLConnection to SQL Azure hangs

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I've this function, wich updates some records on an Azure SQL DB. The function is called every 10 minutes by a timer:

```
    static public bool CaricaOccupazioniiMae(DataTable dtOccupazioni)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetSQLAzureConnectionStringiMae()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlTransaction tr = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                using (SqlCommand SQLCmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE_t_Promemoria", conn))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@CodScuola", mCodiceScuolaiMae);
                        SQLCmd.Transaction = tr;
                        SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        tr.Rollback();
                        tr.Dispose();
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                using (SqlBulkCopy SQLCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, tr))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SQLCopy.DestinationTableName = "t_Promemoria";
                        SQLCopy.WriteToServer(dtOccupazioni);
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        tr.Rollback();
                        tr.Dispose();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                tr.Commit();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

in two occasions the function just hanged in there... The only thing I'm sure of, is that it haven't reach this block, meanwhile it goes through the conn.open():

```
SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@CodScuola", mCodiceScuolaiMae);
SQLCmd.Transaction = tr;
SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

so the logical conclusion is that it hangs in one of those 2 points:

1) SqlTransaction tr = conn.BeginTransaction()

2) SqlCommand SQLCmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE_t_Promemoria", conn);

Have you any clues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How much data is being deleted each time?

Comment: Not more than 300 rows... Could this be a cause? the executenonquery isn't been hit...

Comment: I'm sure of that, because I've added a log write just after "conn.open()" and it's been hit, but the other one just before QLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; isn't been hit

Comment: Now I'm absolutely sure that the code hangs at:
    using (SqlTransaction tr = conn.BeginTransaction())

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't see too much wrong with your code, a bit of refactoring might work. If a transaction is not "committed" it will be rolled back by default and a bit less `try/catch` in there might help avoid resource lock:

```
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetSQLAzureConnectionStringiMae()))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlTransaction tr = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand SQLCmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE_t_Promemoria", conn))
                {
                    SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@CodScuola", mCodiceScuolaiMae);
                    SQLCmd.Transaction = tr;
                    SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                using (SqlBulkCopy SQLCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, tr))
                {
                    SQLCopy.DestinationTableName = "t_Promemoria";
                    SQLCopy.WriteToServer(dtOccupazioni);
                }
                tr.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tr.Rollback();
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you really need to do both SQL operations (`SqlCommand` and `SqlBulkCopy`) in a different transaction, create a new one for each. The way I structured it above does everything in the same transaction and might solve your problem.